# How to find a primitive polynomial for the construction of a Galois field $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

Say I need to construct the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{5^3}$ or $\mathbb{F}_{7^2}$, where do I get a primitive polynomial? Sorry I'm new to learning this and some of what I'm typing may not be making sense.

Comment: The field $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ is the splitting field of $x^{q^n}-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: For $p^n$ where $n$ is $2$ or $3$, it’s relatively easy, since then irreducibility is equivalent to not having a root in $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers I guess I misinterpreted the phrase 'the polynomial'. The above just tells you that it will be a factor of $x^{q^n-1}-1$.

Comment: Do you really need a primitive polynomial? Any irreducible polynomial should do, and there are good algorithms for this (especially one due to Adleman and Lenstra).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say the best way to do this. There is some theory to help construct primitive polynomials (such as finding irreducible factors of certain cyclotomic polynomials, etc.), but I would say that it involves a decent knowledge about finite fields.

Usually if you are doing this as part of a homework assignment, you just check that a polynomial is primitive (this is not too hard for small extension fields).  There are also tables to look up examples. (really, even in common practice among experts you would look these up in a table)

Comment: This is exactly my experience. For small values of $p$ and $n$, just grope around till you find something that works.

Comment: @Morgan Thanks for your answer. Can you maybe lead me to a table, if it's not too much to ask. All that I was able to find is table for polynomials for when $p=2$.

Comment: I found this one that looks pretty good: http://www.comsec.uwaterloo.ca/~ece710t4/2008_spring/table-prim-all.pdf

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thanks so much.

Comment: Agree. I use a table if I need one. I mostly work in characteristic two, so [this table](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~plank/plank/papers/CS-07-593/primitive-polynomial-table.txt) is good enough for me, but not so good here.